# Create Id for the related table when new data is added to the current table MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that needs to be filled in after registration, I have a User and a related Application table.

I want that after user is registered and the data was added to the User table, new Id was created in the Application table

User table

[image]

Application table

[image]

Here I want new ID to be created automatically when data is added to User table (as it is with selected column)

The code I used for registration

```
public void StudentAdd(T p)
{
    c.Set<T>().Add(p);
    c.SaveChanges();
}

registrationRepository.StudentAdd(user);
```

How can I implement that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can do it in your c# code or in a trigger. What have you tried?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

Update the DDL in the table Application  declare that Id column as Auto Increment or Serial,  doing so you don't need to pass the id it will be automatically created.

Comment: i did turn it off earlier, it was not working the way i want,
trigger has helped me.
thanks anyway